# How to perform partial date comparison, ignoring the year, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, object, comparison, partial

As the title says, I'd like to write some basic code that checks if the month, and the day of a given JavaScript `Date` object fall between a certain range. I know that to compare regular dates, one can do the following...

```js
date1 < date2 && date2 > date3
```

But how would one access only the month and the day? I know the `Date` object can return both it's month and it's day, but I'm honestly stumped as to how one could compare only them.

Comment: You can make a copy of one of the dates and change its year to the other date's year, that way you can use the comparison methods in your example.

Comment: @Titus—starting with a Date for say 2016-02-29 and setting the year to 2019 might give unexpected results… ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract a comparable "key" from your date (eg. `month*100+day`) and compare these keys as numbers:

```js
function compareByMD(date1, date2) {
    let a = date1.getMonth() * 100 + date1.getDate();
    let b = date2.getMonth() * 100 + date2.getDate();
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

//

console.log(
    [
        new Date(2009, 7, 15),
        new Date(2011, 8, 3),
        new Date(2019, 5, 3),
        new Date(2022, 7, 13),
    ].sort(compareByMD)
)
```

Comment: Seems like the right amount of hackyness that I'm comfortable with; thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You might add an explanation of why `return a - b` is not sufficient. It seems to me that `(a - b) - (b - a)` => `a - b - b + a` => `2a - 2b` => `2(a-b)`. So I'm left wondering why 2 is a magic number here.

Comment: I still don't see why the last line isn't `return a - b`.